# Question on Eigenvalues/Eigenfunctions in Boundary-Value Problems

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, boundary-value-problem

A simple question, hopefully - consider, for example, the standard BVP defined as follows

$$y^{\prime\prime} + \lambda y = 0\qquad y\left(0\right) = 0 \qquad y\left(2\pi\right) = 0$$

The traditional approach here is to find the eigenvalues and associated eigenfunctions, which would be something like

$$\lambda_n = \dfrac{n^2}{4} \qquad y_n\left(x\right) = \sin\left(\dfrac{n x}{2}\right)$$

Now, this might not be the best question to ask but following this procedure, what exactly will be the final "solution" to the original problem? Will it be a non-trivial linear combination of these eigenfunctions (how do we account for the different $\lambda_n$ in this case) or just the individual eigenfunctions themselves?

Comment: It depends on the original problem. Give the context.

Comment: Well, for this post, I was referencing this page: https://rb.gy/dqzj4m. My original problem, though, is in hydrodynamic stability, where we essentially solve fourth-order linear eigenvalue problems at certain wavenumbers in Fourier space. Physically, for a fluid flow, the wavenumbers represent the (length) “scales” at which the underlying dynamics are occurring. But, if we’re solving such an eigenvalue problem at each such “scale”, what exactly do the resulting eigenfunctions represent (physically, at least)?

Comment: @gettingmathy Your post, as currently written, is an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). That being said, I have some experience in hydrodynamic stability so I will just tell you straight off - they represent **nothing**, physically. This mathematics is just an attempt (a *desperate* attempt) to understand the physical structure of turbulence, which has thus far been unsuccessful.